# syntax error in EL with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have got a xhtml page and there are some labels on it. I am trying to do some labels to be visible according to combobox item selection. These values are at a .txt file. My xhtml is like this:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{myBean.student == '#{properties.grade}'}" value="100"/>
```

But I got Syntax error in EL at my xhtml. How can I render a value from properties.txt file?

Comment: did you Update faces-config.xml ?

Comment: Why do I need that? I just could not express the exact syntax I think.

Comment: No you should update it

Comment: also to call a property in a properties file you should use this syntax : 
#{Var_Declared_In_FACESCONFIG.xml['property']}

Comment: What kind of update do I need?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_internationalization.htm

Comment: <resource-bundle>
      <base-name> ---Location of properties file ---</base-name>
      <var>---Name of variable used to call this file ---</var>
   </resource-bundle>

Comment: I have already getting labels from properties file and I did not do any update at facesconfig.xml. I need exact syntax of my problem I think.

Comment: `#{myBean.student == properties.grade}` should do it.

Comment: You need to explicitly state what the error is. And then search for that error. Btw, @holger is right. And there is a duplicate of this. Nesting EL expressions

Comment: it is not the exact duplicate. I am trying to read the render value from .properties.txt file. I need syntax of inside to inside # usage.

Comment: The fact that you put EL inside quote is wrong. JSF understands that as a string and not an EL. The best solution would be to implement a method in your Controller, write your logic there and call it from the XHTML. By this you would decouple the UI from tha backend.